# How published in Azure my MVC App with support for Identity (Individual User Accounts)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, asp.net-identity

I am developing an MVC App with support for 'Individual User Accounts'. My local App works correctly.
It generates the database correctly, my code...

IdentityModels.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new InitTaxiMetroUserDb());
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}

public class InitTaxiMetroUserDb : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

        if (context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "admin"))
            return;

        var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Administrador"))
            roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Administrador"));
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Flota"))
            roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Flota"));
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Gestor"))
            roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Gestor"));
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Conductor"))
            roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Conductor"));

        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "admin" };
        var result = userManager.Create(user, "123456");
        if (result.Succeeded)
            userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Administrador");

        user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "xxxxx@gmail.com" };
        result = userManager.Create(user, "123456");
        if (result.Succeeded)
            userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Gestor");

        user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "yyyyy@yahoo.es" };
        result = userManager.Create(user, "123456");
        if (result.Succeeded)
            userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Conductor");

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Web.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=TaxiMetroUserDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\TaxiMetroUserDb.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The problem is when I want to publish this App on Azure: does not generate this DB with which I can not perform the authentication. The DB on´t exists in Azure, it isn´t generate, Why??

How should I do it?

Use migration? ... How I can do it

Comment: have you followed this kind of step : http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/

Comment: This example don´t work when you 'Register' or 'Init Session'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are facing with database deploy on Azure check this article and follow the step which is having detail information about publishing local data base on Azure

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/publish-to-azure

[image]

have you done as below during publish wizard of azure

Comment: Yesterday I was just looking at this article, but in any place where I can change this bond with my data

Answer (score 0):

I created my database manually on azure, then used the web.config transform options to modify the database connection strings during the publish operation.